# Quick GDB Question; what does it mean if multiple memory locations are showing up as?

Tags: c++, gdb

```
#1089 0x9999992f in ?? ()
#1090 0x50409a99 in ?? ()
#1091 0x666666a6 in ?? ()
#1092 0x31306666 in ?? ()
#1093 0x35343332 in ?? ()
#1094 0x39383736 in ?? ()
#1095 0x33323130 in ?? ()
#1096 0x37363534 in ?? ()
#1097 0x31303938 in ?? ()
#1098 0x35343332 in ?? ()
#1099 0x39383736 in ?? ()
#1100 0x91403130 in ?? ()
#1101 0x9999992f in ?? ()
#1102 0x50409a99 in ?? ()
#1103 0x666666a6 in ?? ()
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#1104 0x31306666 in ?? ()
#1105 0x35343332 in ?? ()
#1106 0x39383736 in ?? ()
#1107 0x33323130 in ?? ()
#1108 0x37363534 in ?? ()
#1109 0x31303938 in ?? ()
#1110 0x35343332 in ?? ()
#1111 0x39383736 in ?? ()
#1112 0x91403130 in ?? ()
#1113 0x9999992f in ?? ()
#1114 0x50409a99 in ?? ()
#1115 0x666666a6 in ?? ()
#1116 0x31306666 in ?? ()
#1117 0x35343332 in ?? ()
#1118 0x39383736 in ?? ()
#1119 0x33323130 in ?? ()
#1120 0x37363534 in ?? ()
#1121 0x31303938 in ?? ()
#1122 0x35343332 in ?? ()
#1123 0x39383736 in ?? ()
#1124 0x31013130 in ?? ()
#1125 0x0a0a3131 in ?? ()
#1126 0x7473614d in ?? ()
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#1127 0x48203031 in ?? ()
#1128 0x68676965 in ?? ()
#1129 0x2d203a74 in ?? ()
#1130 0x30302e30 in ?? ()
#1131 0x30303030 in ?? ()
#1132 0x73614d0a in ?? ()
#1133 0x20303174 in ?? ()
#1134 0x65746152 in ?? ()
#1135 0x3931203a in ?? ()
#1136 0x39353330 in ?? ()
#1137 0x37363538 in ?? ()
#1138 0x39393135 in ?? ()
#1139 0x34393231 in ?? ()
#1140 0x33323137 in ?? ()
#1141 0x37323830 in ?? ()
#1142 0x32323130 in ?? ()
#1143 0x30323137 in ?? ()
#1144 0x30373234 in ?? ()
#1145 0x37313238 in ?? ()
#1146 0x36373432 in ?? ()
#1147 0x30303235 in ?? ()
#1148 0x39343033 in ?? ()
#1149 0x37333335 in ?? ()
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#1150 0x34323539 in ?? ()
#1151 0x36393036 in ?? ()
#1152 0x34343835 in ?? ()
#1153 0x35303530 in ?? ()
#1154 0x33353032 in ?? ()
#1155 0x37303235 in ?? ()
#1156 0x35323435 in ?? ()
#1157 0x39323736 in ?? ()
#1158 0x32363732 in ?? ()
#1159 0x31323335 in ?? ()
#1160 0x33343939 in ?? ()
#1161 0x37363232 in ?? ()
#1162 0x35353539 in ?? ()
#1163 0x31343332 in ?? ()
#1164 0x35363130 in ?? ()
#1165 0x33383539 in ?? ()
#1166 0x31383230 in ?? ()
#1167 0x39393238 in ?? ()
#1168 0x37363331 in ?? ()
#1169 0x39393831 in ?? ()
#1170 0x37343831 in ?? ()
#1171 0x37333434 in ?? ()
#1172 0x30343535 in ?? ()
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#1173 0x31393731 in ?? ()
#1174 0x39343732 in ?? ()
#1175 0x33303634 in ?? ()
#1176 0x37373338 in ?? ()
#1177 0x34353336 in ?? ()
#1178 0x30323330 in ?? ()
#1179 0x30313937 in ?? ()
#1180 0x34363830 in ?? ()
#1181 0x34323031 in ?? ()
#1182 0x3030302e in ?? ()
#1183 0x0a303030 in ?? ()
#1184 0x7473614d in ?? ()
#1185 0x4e203031 in ?? ()
#1186 0x3a656d61 in ?? ()
#1187 0x32313020 in ?? ()
#1188 0x36353433 in ?? ()
#1189 0x30393837 in ?? ()
#1190 0x34333231 in ?? ()
#1191 0x38373635 in ?? ()
#1192 0x32313039 in ?? ()
#1193 0x36353433 in ?? ()
#1194 0x30393837 in ?? ()
#1195 0x2f914031 in ?? ()
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#1196 0x99999999 in ?? ()
#1197 0xa650409a in ?? ()
#1198 0x66666666 in ?? ()
#1199 0x32313066 in ?? ()
#1200 0x36353433 in ?? ()
#1201 0x30393837 in ?? ()
#1202 0x34333231 in ?? ()
#1203 0x38373635 in ?? ()
#1204 0x32313039 in ?? ()
#1205 0x36353433 in ?? ()
#1206 0x30393837 in ?? ()
#1207 0x2f914031 in ?? ()
#1208 0x99999999 in ?? ()
#1209 0xa650409a in ?? ()
#1210 0x66666666 in ?? ()
#1211 0x32313066 in ?? ()
#1212 0x36353433 in ?? ()
#1213 0x30393837 in ?? ()
#1214 0x34333231 in ?? ()
#1215 0x38373635 in ?? ()
#1216 0x32313039 in ?? ()
#1217 0x36353433 in ?? ()
#1218 0x30393837 in ?? ()
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#1219 0x31310131 in ?? ()
#1220 0x4d0a0a31 in ?? ()
#1221 0x31747361 in ?? ()
#1222 0x65482031 in ?? ()
#1223 0x74686769 in ?? ()
#1224 0x302d203a in ?? ()
#1225 0x3030302e in ?? ()
#1226 0x0a303030 in ?? ()
#1227 0x7473614d in ?? ()
#1228 0x52203131 in ?? ()
#1229 0x3a657461 in ?? ()
#1230 0x30393120 in ?? ()
#1231 0x38393533 in ?? ()
#1232 0x35373635 in ?? ()
#1233 0x31393931 in ?? ()
#1234 0x37343932 in ?? ()
#1235 0x30333231 in ?? ()
#1236 0x30373238 in ?? ()
#1237 0x37323231 in ?? ()
#1238 0x34303231 in ?? ()
#1239 0x38303732 in ?? ()
#1240 0x32373132 in ?? ()
#1241 0x35363734 in ?? ()
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#1242 0x33303032 in ?? ()
#1243 0x35393430 in ?? ()
#1244 0x39373333 in ?? ()
#1245 0x36343235 in ?? ()
#1246 0x35363930 in ?? ()
#1247 0x30343438 in ?? ()
#1248 0x32353035 in ?? ()
#1249 0x35333530 in ?? ()
#1250 0x35373032 in ?? ()
#1251 0x36353234 in ?? ()
#1252 0x32393237 in ?? ()
#1253 0x35323637 in ?? ()
#1254 0x39313233 in ?? ()
#1255 0x32333439 in ?? ()
#1256 0x39373632 in ?? ()
#1257 0x32353535 in ?? ()
#1258 0x30313433 in ?? ()
#1259 0x39353631 in ?? ()
#1260 0x30333835 in ?? ()
#1261 0x38313832 in ?? ()
#1262 0x31393932 in ?? ()
#1263 0x31373633 in ?? ()
#1264 0x31393938 in ?? ()
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#1265 0x34373438 in ?? ()
#1266 0x35373334 in ?? ()
#1267 0x31303435 in ?? ()
#1268 0x32313937 in ?? ()
#1269 0x34393437 in ?? ()
#1270 0x38333036 in ?? ()
#1271 0x36373733 in ?? ()
#1272 0x30343533 in ?? ()
#1273 0x37303233 in ?? ()
#1274 0x30303139 in ?? ()
#1275 0x31343638 in ?? ()
#1276 0x2e343230 in ?? ()
#1277 0x30303030 in ?? ()
#1278 0x4d0a3030 in ?? ()
#1279 0x31747361 in ?? ()
#1280 0x614e2031 in ?? ()
#1281 0x203a656d in ?? ()
#1282 0x33323130 in ?? ()
#1283 0x37363534 in ?? ()
#1284 0x31303938 in ?? ()
#1285 0x35343332 in ?? ()
#1286 0x39383736 in ?? ()
#1287 0x33323130 in ?? ()
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#1288 0x37363534 in ?? ()
#1289 0x31303938 in ?? ()
#1290 0x992f9140 in ?? ()
#1291 0x9a999999 in ?? ()
#1292 0x66a65040 in ?? ()
#1293 0x66666666 in ?? ()
#1294 0x33323130 in ?? ()
#1295 0x37363534 in ?? ()
#1296 0x31303938 in ?? ()
#1297 0x35343332 in ?? ()
#1298 0x39383736 in ?? ()
#1299 0x33323130 in ?? ()
#1300 0x37363534 in ?? ()
#1301 0x31303938 in ?? ()
#1302 0x31313101 in ?? ()
#1303 0x614d0a0a in ?? ()
#1304 0x32317473 in ?? ()
#1305 0x69654820 in ?? ()
#1306 0x3a746867 in ?? ()
#1307 0x2e302d20 in ?? ()
#1308 0x30303030 in ?? ()
#1309 0x4d0a3030 in ?? ()
#1310 0x31747361 in ?? ()
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#1311 0x61522032 in ?? ()
#1312 0x203a6574 in ?? ()
#1313 0x33303931 in ?? ()
#1314 0x35383935 in ?? ()
#1315 0x31353736 in ?? ()
#1316 0x32313939 in ?? ()
#1317 0x31373439 in ?? ()
#1318 0x38303332 in ?? ()
#1319 0x31303732 in ?? ()
#1320 0x31373232 in ?? ()
#1321 0x32343032 in ?? ()
#1322 0x32383037 in ?? ()
#1323 0x34323731 in ?? ()
#1324 0x32353637 in ?? ()
#1325 0x30333030 in ?? ()
#1326 0x33353934 in ?? ()
#1327 0x35393733 in ?? ()
#1328 0x30363432 in ?? ()
#1329 0x38353639 in ?? ()
#1330 0x35303434 in ?? ()
#1331 0x30323530 in ?? ()
#1332 0x32353335 in ?? ()
#1333 0x34353730 in ?? ()
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#1334 0x37363532 in ?? ()
#1335 0x37323932 in ?? ()
#1336 0x33353236 in ?? ()
#1337 0x39393132 in ?? ()
#1338 0x32323334 in ?? ()
#1339 0x35393736 in ?? ()
#1340 0x33323535 in ?? ()
#1341 0x31303134 in ?? ()
#1342 0x35393536 in ?? ()
#1343 0x32303338 in ?? ()
#1344 0x32383138 in ?? ()
#1345 0x33313939 in ?? ()
#1346 0x38313736 in ?? ()
#1347 0x38313939 in ?? ()
#1348 0x34343734 in ?? ()
#1349 0x35353733 in ?? ()
#1350 0x37313034 in ?? ()
#1351 0x37323139 in ?? ()
#1352 0x36343934 in ?? ()
#1353 0x33383330 in ?? ()
#1354 0x33363737 in ?? ()
#1355 0x33303435 in ?? ()
#1356 0x39373032 in ?? ()
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#1357 0x38303031 in ?? ()
#1358 0x30313436 in ?? ()
#1359 0x302e3432 in ?? ()
#1360 0x30303030 in ?? ()
#1361 0x614d0a30 in ?? ()
#1362 0x32317473 in ?? ()
#1363 0x6d614e20 in ?? ()
#1364 0x30203a65 in ?? ()
#1365 0x34333231 in ?? ()
#1366 0x38373635 in ?? ()
#1367 0x32313039 in ?? ()
#1368 0x36353433 in ?? ()
#1369 0x30393837 in ?? ()
#1370 0x34333231 in ?? ()
#1371 0x38373635 in ?? ()
#1372 0x01313039 in ?? ()
#1373 0x0a313131 in ?? ()
#1374 0x475f000a in ?? ()
#1375 0x313d4955 in ?? ()
#1376 0x45544400 in ?? ()
#1377 0x505f3144 in ?? ()
#1378 0x3d485441 in ?? ()
#1379 0x7273752f in ?? ()
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#1380 0x6973702f in ?? ()
#1381 0x702f586d in ?? ()
#1382 0x646d6973 in ?? ()
#1383 0x2f617461 in ?? ()
#1384 0x6574642f in ?? ()
#1385 0x50003164 in ?? ()
#1386 0x5f4d4953 in ?? ()
#1387 0x4d564155 in ?? ()
#1388 0x4c45444f in ?? ()
#1389 0x7661753d in ?? ()
#1390 0x4e414c00 in ?? ()
#1391 0x6e653d47 in ?? ()
#1392 0x2e53555f in ?? ()
#1393 0x2d465455 in ?? ()
#1394 0x444b0038 in ?? ()
#1395 0x53495f45 in ?? ()
#1396 0x4552505f in ?? ()
#1397 0x4b4e494c in ?? ()
#1398 0x313d4445 in ?? ()
#1399 0x49535000 in ?? ()
#1400 0x43535f4d in ?? ()
#1401 0x5f454e45 in ?? ()
#1402 0x5054554f in ?? ()
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#1403 0x2f3d5455 in ?? ()
#1404 0x2f727375 in ?? ()
#1405 0x6d697370 in ?? ()
#1406 0x73702f58 in ?? ()
#1407 0x2f2f6d69 in ?? ()
#1408 0x666e6f63 in ?? ()
#1409 0x2f2f6769 in ?? ()
#1410 0x65766173 in ?? ()
#1411 0x65635364 in ?? ()
#1412 0x6972616e in ?? ()
#1413 0x63732e6f in ?? ()
#1414 0x41006766 in ?? ()
#1415 0x5f535355 in ?? ()
#1416 0x504f4353 in ?? ()
#1417 0x564f5f45 in ?? ()
#1418 0x49525245 in ?? ()
#1419 0x303d4544 in ?? ()
#1420 0x49535000 in ?? ()
#1421 0x53415f4d in ?? ()
#1422 0x752f3d4d in ?? ()
#1423 0x702f7273 in ?? ()
#1424 0x586d6973 in ?? ()
#1425 0x6973702f in ?? ()
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#1426 0x73612f6d in ?? ()
#1427 0x41002f6d in ?? ()
#1428 0x5f535355 in ?? ()
#1429 0x44415453 in ?? ()
#1430 0x4a44415f in ?? ()
#1431 0x3d545355 in ?? ()
#1432 0x4c003033 in ?? ()
#1433 0x53524d41 in ?? ()
#1434 0x73733d48 in ?? ()
#1435 0x782d2068 in ?? ()
#1436 0x52455600 in ?? ()
#1437 0x41434954 in ?? ()
#1438 0x4f465f4c in ?? ()
#1439 0x44415f56 in ?? ()
#1440 0x49544944 in ?? ()
#1441 0x313d4e4f in ?? ()
#1442 0x49440035 in ?? ()
#1443 0x4e415453 in ?? ()
#1444 0x455f4543 in ?? ()
#1445 0x5f545341 in ?? ()
#1446 0x575f4f54 in ?? ()
#1447 0x3d545345 in ?? ()
#1448 0x00303531 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libXm.so.4
```

... And it continues to #1.  Does the above output mean that several memory addresses are being written to that do not exist?

Comment: Are there symbols compiled in the code?

Comment: That is a backtrace.  The code, in C++, tries to read in a contiguous buffer of data and tries to copy it into a C++ structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me it looks like your stack is trashed.

```
0x52455600 is REV (or VER)
0x41434954 is ACIT (or TICA)
0x4f465f4c is OF_L (or L_FO)
0x2f2f6769 is //gi (or gi//)
0x65766173 is  evas (or save)!
0x65746152 is etaR (or Rate)!
```

Most of the remaining addresses seem to give nice ascii characters.

You might have overflown a buffer.

Comment: I have no idea why somebody is downvoting perfectly good answers, so here's an upvote.

Comment: Because the answer is likely wrong. There is no question the stack *is* bogus. But the root cause is very likely *not* stack corruption, but mismatched binaries.

Comment: @Emp: If you look at the addresses, there seem to be wild jumps in there. For eg: 0x20... to 0x70... to 0x30.... I would expect some locality of reference in those. Plus most of the addresses seem to be nice ascii characters and some address repeat at odd places which makes for a strange recursive method. OP also says they were trying to copy a buffer into a struct. Looks like a buffer/memory overflow to me.

Answer (score 2):

It means the debugger have no clue what those memory addresses are. This could be because debugging information is missing for the stuff you're debugging - e.g. inside a library that doesn't have debug information.

Though seeing such a long trace usually means you've smashed the stack, overwritten information the debugger needs, lead your program so far astray neither the debugger nor the program have any clue left as to what's going on. (i.e. you've a buffer overflow somewhere, fire up valgrind and try to find it)